# I can read from google sheet api once but it doesn't update subsequently

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am new to Google Sheets, and I have a Google Sheet that I have set up to dynamically place the present date in cell A1 and the time in cell A2. The sheet is "published to the web", and "Settings/Calculation" is set to Recalculate change every minute.

That all works fine, but I want to be able to read these values from the sheet using an API call. Also works perfectly, the FIRST TIME. Unfortunately, every time I try to call it again, I get the same answer as the first time, even a day later.

I'm using:

```
=int(hour(now()))&":"&int(minute(now()))&" "&int(SECOND(now()))
```

as the formula. I should also add that it's a JSON file that I'm reading and it is updating properly on the actual sheet.

I'm sure that I am missing something. Can someone please tell me what it is?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the now() function ?

Comment: I'm using:
=int(hour(now()))&":"&int(minute(now()))&" "&int(SECOND(now()))

I should add that it's a JSON file that I'm reading and it is updating properly on thge actgual shee.

Comment: You should add that detail to your actual question so people don't have to trawl through comments...

Comment: What is the code of your API call, did you try updating the sheet (with API) before reading the values?

Comment: this is the API
 https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1TtXe1JXKsxHKUWb3bqniHkLQB0Po1fSUqsiib2yMv90/1/public/values?alt=json

Comment: The formula I used I got from Excel

Comment: Check the [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values). There are [sample code snippets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) for code reference. Make sure you're familiar with [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).

Answer (score 0):

may be you are not reading the JSON correctly. This give me correct result every time I run it.

```
function myFunction(){
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1TtXe1JXKsxHKUWb3bqniHkLQB0Po1fSUqsiib2yMv90/1/public/values?alt=json";
try{
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
var str = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(response);
var entry = data.feed.entry;
sh.getRange(1, 1).setValue(entry[0].content.$t);
sh.getRange(1, 2).setValue(entry[1].content.$t);
}catch(e){
Logger.log(e);
}
}
```

You need to check the size of "entry" before reading it, I just wanted to show that it works.

Thanks